# Canvas se limpia automaticamente

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, alertdialog

pues estoy haciendo una aplicación en **Android Studio**, en esta aplicación utilizo **Canvas** como lienzo de escritura pues mi meta es imprimir en el canvas una ecuación matemática, el problema está que cuando ingreso los datos desde un **Custom Dialog** con un **EditText** y presiono sobre botón aceptar para que el canvas se pinte, efectivamente pasa pero el canvas se limpia automáticamente cuando el teclado virtual se cierra, he notado que solo pasa con el teclado virtual porque he probado con un teclado físico y todo va perfecto!

Cabe destacar que no es el mismo problema que causa por ejemplo cuando se pasa de landscape a portraint o viceversa. El contenido de las variables no se pierde, el problema es solo el canvas que se limpia.

el canvas está en una clase diferente al **MainActivity**

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda o recomendación para poder investigar, gracias!

[image: Ingresando datos][image: Impresión del canvas][image: Se limpia automáticamente cuando el teclado virtual se oculta]

Comment: Encontre un enlace que te puede ayudar a encontrar el problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812766/canvas-disappear-with-soft-keyboard-on-android

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ha dado una idea.